# Social media sharing buttons

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

What is the correct links for sharing content on user's social media pages/profile? Something similar to the web page sharing links:

```
https://facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=xxxx
https://twitter.com/home?status=xxx
```

I know that instead of "xxxx" you have to put your page url which you want to be shared. Exemple when I press the share button (facebook): [08rnz.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08rnz.png) . I need links for more social media's sharing and via e-mail too.

So if I put https://facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=site.com/site/index.html it doesn't work.  It's any scripts for those sharing buttons? What exactly I have to do? I want for: facebook, twiiter, google plus, e-mail, whatsapp.

Thank you!

Comment: You cant share localhost page on FB.

Comment: I uploaded my website on 000webhost.com and also doesn't work.

Comment: it is unclear what you are asking. ... `"xxxx" you have to put your page url` .... `localhost/site/index.html`  is not a valid url

Comment: `https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=000webhost.com` <- Works fine on my end

Comment: an how can I do it for e-mail, whatsapp?

Comment: You have to research on it my friend. This is not a free coding service. We can help but not make the codes for you.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You might want to look into: [addthis.com](https://www.addthis.com/), you can use this website to generate share buttons for your website.
It creates a script, that you have to add to your webpage.

You have probably seen the buttons before, since they are used a lot.

What you need to do:

1. get a (free) account on their website
2. you can design your share buttons in your addthis account
3. generate and copy the javascript (script tags) to the bottom of your page, just before the closing body element

Comment: If you want to replace few lines of code with hundreds of unnecessary lines of code, slowing down the website, calling for resources from other websites, iframes and other stuff that Google just loves...

Comment: @StoychoTrenchev I believe that's not related. The question mentioned: It's any scripts for those sharing buttons? , which i translated into something like: Is there a script out there which can help me.

Answer (score 1):

This service could be helpful:
sharelinkgenerator.com

But your problem is most probably with localhost. It is not an internet address, just your local server.

Update:

For sharing by email:

```
<a href="mailto:?subject=Recommending&amp;body=Recommend this post." title="Email Sharing">Share</a>
```

For Whatsapp:

```
<a href = "whatsapp://send?text=google.com">Share on Whatsapp</a>
```

Comment: I need for e-mail and whatsapp too.

Comment: Do you mean something different than <a href="mailto:your_email@address.com">Email me</a>?

Comment: yes cause I want to share that "post" via e-mail means like I want to share it to a friend so I have to write his e-mail to send that post, not to send it to that person which I write by default the e-mail at "mailto".